# apache virtual host for nagios on ubuntu 14

Tags: 14.04, apache2, virtualhost, nagios3

I have just installed nagios on Ubuntu 14 LTS with Apache, i am accessing the site through example.com/nagios3, however i want to use a virtual host for access the nagios like nagios.example.com. what is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assumptions

1. Standard Apache2 server is installed from Ubuntu repos and no changes have been made to the default installation
2. Nagios is installed in /var/www/ folder by default having the folder name as nagios3
3. Nagios.example.com resolves to a valid IP address and is the same as the nagios server

Steps to use nagios as nagios.example.com – SSH into the server and run following commands
1. cd /etc/apache2/sites-available
2. sudo cp default nagios.example.com
3. sudo nano nagios.example.com
4. It should look like this – Dont copy paste this code. Just add the entries which I have mentioned on line number 4, 5, 6 and 11

```
 NameVirtualHost *    
 <VirtualHost *>  
     ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost  
     ServerName nagios.example.com # Add this line
     ServerAlias    nagios # Add this line
     DocumentRoot /var/www/nagios3 # Add nagios3 at the end of this line
    <Directory /> 
            Options FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride None
    </Directory>
    <Directory /var/www/nagios3/>
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
            AllowOverride None
            Order allow,deny
            allow from all
            RedirectMatch ^/$ /apache2-default/
    </Directory>

    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
    <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
            AllowOverride None
            Options ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
            Order allow,deny
            Allow from all
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/error.log

    # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
    # alert, emerg.
    LogLevel warn

    CustomLog /var/log/apache2/access.log combined
    ServerSignature On

Alias /doc/ "/usr/share/doc/"
<Directory "/usr/share/doc/">
    Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
    Allow from 127.0.0.0/255.0.0.0 ::1/128
</Directory>
```

1. ^ O (for saving the file)
2. ^ X (for exiting the nano edior)
3. sudo a2ensite nagios.example.com (this is for enabling the virtual host)
4. sudo service apache2 restart
5. Open the browser and type http://nagios.example.com and you should be able to see the nagios login page (ensure nagios.example.com can be resolved from the machine which you are using for accessing nagios - if you cant make an entry in the local hosts file)

Hope this helps
Regards